# Change node pm2 git remote url for deployed project

Tags: node.js, git, pm2

I have a service deployed fetching changes from a git repository.
I want to change it to fetch from a different repository.
I have changed the local ecosystem.json file and pulled the changes to the old repository but when I type `pm2 list` I still see the old repository.

How can i force pm2 to fetch from the new repository?

Comment: Any updates here? I'm trying the same

Comment: its not possible. you have to delete the deploy and re-deploy